# no suitable windowing system found, exiting. open office 4 ubuntu

Tags: openoffice.org

I am running open office 4 soffice headless on Ubuntu 64 bit on my VPS with command line.

```
/usr/bin/soffice -accept=socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager -norestore -nofirststartwizard -nologo -headless
```

Its exiting with an error.

```
no suitable windowing system found, exiting.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to install package libxt6 and libxrender1

> apt-get install libxt6
>   apt-get install libxrender1

Comment: What is this for @mayank jain
In server, I don't want to show any output, I want to just run that command

Comment: What is the explanation behind this installation?